# How do i get Backspace to remove only the last letter in my Calculator?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have tried a couple of things, but i don't really know what i am doing. So i want that my backspace delets the last input in my calc

I've done this for other keys:

```
$("body").keypress(function (event) {
    let key = event.which;
    let value = "";
    console.log(event.which);

    switch (key) {
        case 49:
            value = $("#display").val();
            $("#display").val(value += '1');
            console.log("one");
            break;
        case 50:
            value = $("#display").val();
            $("#display").val(value += '2');
            console.log("two");
            break;
```

I've tried to do this for backspace but it seems to be wrong.

```
    $("body").keydown(function (event) {
        let key = event.which;
        let value = "";
        console.log(event.which);

        var Key = event.keydown;
        switch (Key) {
            case 8:
                document.getElementById("d").value = value.length - 1;
                console.log("backspace");


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the last character of it using `slice()`

```
$("body").keydown(function (event) {
        let key = event.which;
        let value = "";
        let realVal = document.getElementById("d").value
        console.log(event.which);

        var Key = event.keydown;
        switch (Key) {
            case 8:
                document.getElementById("d").value = realVal.slice(0,realVal.length -1)
                console.log("backspace");


        }
    });
```